# How many words of length n with letters from {A,B,C} with atleast 1 occurence of AA?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I want to find a recursive formula to determine the amount of different words that you can build by taking n letters from the set {a,b,c}. Also, there needs to be atleast on occurence of two consecutive a's in the word. For example, baac is a valid word, but abac is not.

How would you approach this?

Comment: Well, there are $3^{n-2}$ words that start with $aa$. Similarly, there are $3^{n-2}$ word with $aa$ as the second and third characters... now continue shifting  $aa$ to the right and sum up all the possible words you get $(n-1)3^{n-2}$.

Comment: @TSU That is incorrect.  You have counted several of these multiple times.  Note that for $n>10$ you have $(n-1)3^{n-2}>3^n$

Comment: As for a correct approach... it is easier to count the number which *don't* have any consecutive $a$'s via a recurrence relation and subtract that number away from the total.

Comment: Wops, you are right!